# Putting a division of 10 px more then the size of image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know why this is not working, I want the `div` to be more then the size of image?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            var a = $('#img').clientWidth;
            $('#viewimg').css('width', +a);
            var b = $('#img').clientHeight;
            $('#viewimg').css('height', +b);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <  div  style="he"">
      <div id="viewimg">
        <p>asdsa
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <img id="img" src="https://www.google.com/intl/es_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" style= border:dotted 1px;"/>
      <div class="t">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why you are adding + to the variables

Comment: Do you want to add the height and width of #img with the height and width of #viewimg  and assign it to the height and width of #viewimg OR just assign the height and width of #img to the height and width of #viewimg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting `padding` (top & left) or `margin` (top & left) will do the work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var extraSpace = 15;//pixels
        var img = $("#img");
        var div = $("#viewimg");
        img.css('margin-left', extraSpace/2);
        img.css('margin-top', extraSpace/2);
        var a = img.width();
        var b = img.height();
        div.css('width', a+extraSpace);
        div.css('height', b+extraSpace);
});​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dkr3A/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `clientWidth` on a jQuery object just like that. Take a look at this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hewnR/1/

If you want to access the DOM element matched by the jQuery object, you need to use `.get()`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/get/). But it would be easier if you use jQuery's method `.width()` instead of `.get(0).clientWidth`.

```
//This doesn't work:
var a = $('#img').clientWidth;

//But this does:
var a = $('#img').get(0).clientWidth;
//and does the same as this:
var a = $('#img').width();

//Then, add 10px and change the width:
$('#viewimg').width(10+a+'px');
```

Comment: I wanted to get the image 's wigth  ( IMG element after loading image ) . This is giving me only for a DIV not IMG element

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= $('#img').width();
$('#viewimg').width(a+10) ; // $('#viewimg').css('width', a+10);
```